# How to connect my API to MariaDB in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, mariadb, fastapi

I'm making an API in python with fastAPI and I can deploy it normally using uvicorn in the console, but when I try to do it in a docker container, this error comes up
;

```
2024-03-08 19:35:57 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-03-08 19:35:57   File "/usr/src/app/./app.py", line 5, in <module>
2024-03-08 19:35:57     from MariaDB.MariaRouter.MariaRouter import maria_router
2024-03-08 19:35:57   File "/usr/src/app/MariaDB/MariaRouter/MariaRouter.py", line 12, in <module>
2024-03-08 19:35:57     note_maria_repo = MariaNoteRepository()
2024-03-08 19:35:57                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-08 19:35:57   File "/usr/src/app/MariaDB/MariaRepository/MariaNoteRepository.py", line 12, in __init__
2024-03-08 19:35:57     self.connection = mariadb.connect(
2024-03-08 19:35:57                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-08 19:35:57   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mariadb/__init__.py", line 146, in connect
2024-03-08 19:35:57     connection = connectionclass(*args, **kwargs)
2024-03-08 19:35:57                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-03-08 19:35:57   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mariadb/connections.py", line 85, in __init__
2024-03-08 19:35:57     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
2024-03-08 19:35:57 mariadb.OperationalError: Can't connect to server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
```

This is the docker compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:6.0.13-jammy
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: testdb

  maria:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --bind-address=0.0.0.0

  api:
    build: api/.
    depends_on:
      - maria
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - PORT=8000


volumes:
  mongodb:
  mariadb:
```

Comment: use 'maria', the service name, as the hostname in the application connection.